# How to send token to php verifier on Google Sign In?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

So, I'm trying to implement Google Sign In into a site to add more security and ways to log in, prior to this, the only way to log in, was via a 8-9 digit number as a user, and a 4 digit pin, right now, i'm trying to implement Google Sign In with the email the company provides.

Right now I have the Google Sign In button working kind of okay, this is what I have:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
         data-auto_select="false"
         data-itp_support="true"
         data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
         data-auto_prompt="false"
         data-ux_mode="redirect"
         data-login_uri="http://localhost/verifier.php"
         redirect_uri="http://localhost/verifier.php"
         data-hd="xxx"
         data-locale="vi"
         data-callback="callbackfunction">
    </div>
        <div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard" data-shape="pill"
            data-theme="outline"
            data-text="continue_with"
            data-size="large"
            data-locale="es-419"
            data-logo_alignment="left">      
        </div>
        <p id="account"></p>
  </body>
  <script>
    function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
      const responsePayload = decodeJwtResponse(response.credential);
      console.log('ID: '+responsePayload.sub); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
      console.log('Name: ' + responsePayload.name);
      console.log('Image URL: '+responsePayload.aud);
      console.log('Email: ' + responsePayload.email); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
      var username = responsePayload.email;
      numerocontrol=numerocontrol.split('@')[0];
      console.log(username);
      document.getElementById('account').innerHTML='welcome '+ responsePayload.name+' /// '+username;
    }
    function decodeJwtResponse(token) {
        var base64Url = token.split(".")[1];
        var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");
        var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(
          atob(base64)
            .split("")
            .map(function (c) {
              return "%" + ("00" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            })
            .join("")
        );

        return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
    }
  </script>
```

(The Scripts were just for testing if it was working and getting the username of the email correctly as well for the p with the "account" id as i need to show after the login just the user that is signed in).

From here, I'm not really sure what is next to be done, I kind of got the idea to send the JWT Token to the verifier.php to do the verification on the server side and after doing the verification, redirect to the main page where you can see the user that is signed in, but I'm not really sure how to do this, or what needs to be added, and what needs to be in the verifier.php, as of right now just have this but not working:

```
<?php
require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\google-api-php-client--PHP8.0\vendor\autoload.php';
$CLIENT_ID= 'xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
$id_token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjFhYWU4ZDdjOTIwNThiNWVlYTQ1Njg5NWJmODkwODQ1NzFlMzA2ZjMiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ
// Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.

$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
  $userid = $payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //$domain = $payload['hd'];
} else {
  // Invalid ID token
}

?>
```

In here, I'm not really sure what is the $id_token variable, not sure if it is a constant or where to get it, I found it in other post, but doesn't explain what it is or where to get it.

This drops the error:
 `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$id_token" in C:\xampp\htdocs\verifier.php on line 4`
I would really appreciate the help and explanation if possible. I've been reading a lot of documentation and post of how to do this, but I haven't make it work, and some didn't undertand quite well.
And, just for clarification, yes, I need to use PHP and Google Sign In.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example, you had `data-ux_mode="redirect"` and `data-login_uri="http://localhost/verifier.php"`. Hence, the `data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"` is ignored. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-callback).

Basically, in your code example, users sign in and give the consent. Then, Google returns an ID token through the HTTP `POST` method request to the `http://localhost/verifier.php`. You can access the ID token in the `POST` body with the parameter name `credential`.

It would be something like `$id_token = $_POST['credential']` to set the `$id_token` value.

You can find more information [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token).